# MySQL events -- EVENT privilege required for execution?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7 (Win) & MariaDB 10.1 (Linux), Event Scheduler set to ON, I'm connected as root.

```
CREATE DATABASE `event-test`;

CREATE USER 'event-test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password-is-here';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'event-test'@'localhost';
GRANT EXECUTE, SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE ON `event-test`.* TO 'event-test'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

USE `event-test`;

CREATE TABLE t (
    v INT(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO t (v) VALUES (0);

DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`event-test`@`localhost` EVENT `e`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET v = v + 1;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

=>

Database, table & event created.
Waiting a few minutes -- t.v still zero.

In error log:

> 2020-01-13T03:30:00.184167Z 16332 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [event-test@localhost].[event-test.e] execution failed, user no longer has EVENT privilege.
>
> 2020-01-13T03:30:00.185852Z 16332 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [event-test@localhost][event-test.e] Access denied for user 'event-test'@'localhost' to database 'event-test'
>
> 2020-01-13T03:30:00.187426Z 16332 [Note] Event Scheduler: [event-test@localhost].[event-test.e] event execution failed.

If I give EVENT privilege to the user with command:

```
GRANT EVENT ON `event-test`.* TO 'event-test'@'localhost';
```

t.v will be incremented every minute and no more errors in log.

Based by [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-privileges.html), EVENT privilege only required for creating/updating/deleting EVENT.

So my question is: what am I missing?
Why the EVENT privilege required for the event to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible reason may be in `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE`  - removing action needs in `EVENT` privilege. Try to remove this clause (it makes no sense when event expire not specified) or change it to `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`.

Comment: Changed event and replace "NOT PRESERVE" with "PRESERVE" and there is still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ON COMPLETION clause implies an action at the completion of the event.  The EVENT privilege is required to execute that action.

If your intent is to continue the action every minute, you should remove that clause entirely.

If your intent is to only run the event for a limited time, then you need to specify the ENDS time and grant the user the EVENT privilege in order to remove the event at that time.